# Permissions issue when trying to install Symfony Application with Composer

Tags: php, windows, symfony, composer-php

**Please refrain from commenting your suggestion unless you've read through my list of troubleshooting steps. I am updating this list as suggestions come in.**

On my co-worker's Windows 7 environment, when trying to install one of our apps built on Symfony 2.5.*, we get the following problem with `unlink`:

[image: Composer Install Error]

We have tried the following:

- Running `composer self-update`
- Running `composer update` instead of `composer install` (which resulted in the same error below)
- Running the git bash in Administrator mode
- Running `composer install` from an Administrator DOS shell instead of the git bash
- Cloning our repository in multiple locations, including directly on the User Desktop
- Changing the permissions of the files to give full control and ownership to the current user (recursively)
- Changing the permissions of the files to give full control and ownership to "Everybody" (recursively)
- Changing the permissions of the files to give full control and ownership to "SYSTEM" (recursively)
- Starting a new project from scratch using `composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition test/ "2.5.*"` and `composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition path/ "2.3.*"` (in case the issue is version-specific)
- Trying on a different Windows 7 machine (with the same result)
- Removing the vendor folder and clearing the composer cache
- Turning off the Indexer (Windows Search System)

Any ideas on what's going on? Is this a composer bug, or one of the pleasures of working with Windows? Everything above runs fine on my OSX machine.

Another debugging note... when I try to manually unlink with `php -r "unlink('...');"` it deletes the file in question no problems

Comment: run sudo composer self-update

Comment: Try removing your entire vendor dir and running it again using admin mode?

Comment: @johnSmith there is no `sudo` in Windows. I have run self update as an administrator however

Comment: @Chausser have tried this - doesn't work still. Have also started with a fresh clone several times (the repo doesn't store a vendor folder)

Comment: then maybe you have no other chance than setting for each step the correct permissions ( could be a lot ) with right click setting security ownership take ownership and grant all permissions

Comment: I understand that this is a private repo but any chance you would be willing to grant me access to see if i can replicate the issue and provide a fix?

Comment: @johnSmith This doesn't help since the cache file with the permission issue is created when `composer install` is executed. You'll notice what you suggested is also in my list of "things we've tried"

Comment: Try setting the permission on the entire installation directory of your symfony project, set owner to Everyone and give them all permissions (change later on)

Comment: @Chausser `composer create-project` from a fresh Symfony install gives me the same problem (see my edit), so you should be able to reproduce the issue that way.

Comment: Can you manually remove the vendor folder ? And is there a reason that you are using git bash ?

Comment: @MaximGeerinck Yes. Doesn't help

Comment: @MaximGeerinck Better *nix-like environment to work in. Working with Command Prompt makes no difference

Comment: if using ```composer create-project``` gives you the same issue then it not an issue with the repo, it is likely an issue with your windows setup. can you use ```composer create-project``` from a cmd.exe not git bash? does it give the same error?

Comment: @Chausser like previously stated, yes. And I've tried this with 2 Win7 machines now. It could be a Windows domain/profile configuration but I'm not certain.

Comment: Confirming you have tried the following variation: cmd.exe -> composer create-project /c/Users/USERNAME/Documents/ProjectFolder ?

Comment: @Chausser Yes. Both as an Administrator and as a regular user

Comment: Lets continue this conversation in chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56143/room-for-chausser-and-sjagr

Comment: try to remove everything in the folder vendor and the composer.lock then try php composer.phar install

Comment: @MirzaSelimovic Have tried this, no joy

Comment: Have you set the permission of the right user? Could you run following code `echo exec('whoami');`.

Comment: @GuyT `dunhamgroup-pc\dunham group`

Comment: And you have set the right permissions for that user/group?

Comment: What you also can try is to open your taskmanager and look for `httpd.exe`(see User Name) --> right click --> properties --> security tab. In normal installations the user will be `SYSTEM` and needs the proper permissions.

Comment: @GuyT repeatedly tried changing the owner to either "Dunham Group" or "Everyone" recursively for the project (it's in my troubleshooting steps)
Changed the owner from "Administrators" to "Dunham Group" on `httpd.exe`, still no success

Comment: And if you give user `SYSTEM` on both(htdocs and httpd.exe) with full priveleges?

Comment: @GuyT Trying this, but why is `httpd.exe` relevant? `composer` (or rather, `php`) runs independently from this program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the issue. An office-wide anti-virus program called "Trend Micro" was doing a "live scanning" of any newly created files. Since the anti-virus program was accessing the file at the same time composer was trying to `unlink` the files, composer would fail. Adding the repository as to the anti-virus whitelist (as well as the Windows Indexer to be safe) fixed the problem entirely.

I [have created an issue in GitHub for the composer team to work on](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/3074) so that this exception could be handled somehow (e.g. a `sleep` function upon failure of the `unlink`)

Thanks for the troubleshooting help, everyone.

EDIT: As of this edit, a fix has been written, so if you run into this problem, just run `composer self-update` to ensure Composer has the latest fix for this.